# How to create an new screen on the modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a modal screen using `presentation: 'modal'` ,I want to make a new screen above this modal, but the new screen is under the modal screen.

My demo (FeedBack screen under the Setting screen.):

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from '@/views/Home';
import Setting from '@/views/Setting';
import Feedback from '@/views/Setting/Feedback';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
          />
          <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Setting"
              component={Setting}
              options={{
                headerTitle: 'Setting',
                headerLargeTitle: true,
                headerTransparent: true,
                headerBlurEffect: 'systemMaterial',
                presentation: 'modal',
              }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Feedback"
              component={Feedback}
              options={{
                title: 'Feedback',
                headerLargeTitle: true,
                headerTransparent: true,
                headerBlurEffect: 'systemMaterial',
                presentation: 'card'
              }}
            />
           
            </Stack.Group>
          </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I want the FeedBack screen above the Setting modal and close both screen when I slide down.